# Remove part of string after or before a specific word in java

Tags: java

Is there a command in java to remove the rest of the string after or before a certain word;

Example:

Remove substring before the word "taken"

before:
"I need this words removed taken please"

after:

"taken please"

Answer (score 8):

**String are immutable, you can however find the word and create a substring**:

```
public static String removeTillWord(String input, String word) {
    return input.substring(input.indexOf(word));
}

removeTillWord("I need this words removed taken please", "taken");
```

Comment: missing return type :D

Comment: What if we have a repetitive word in the input string and want to remove second repetitive word?

Comment: use ``return input.substring(input.indexOf(word) +word.length())`` if you want to remove including the  word taken

Answer (score 5):

There is `apache-commons-lang` class [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) that contains exactly you want:

e.g. `public static String substringBefore(String str, String separator)`

Comment: This will also remove `separator` which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Pshemo and what? I think he really wants so

Comment: From question "*Remove substring before the word `"taken"`*" which OP explains as: *before `"I need this words removed taken please"` after: `"taken please"`* so as you see `"taken"` is part of result (after) so it was not removed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not saying that your approach is bad. I am just pointing that it needs some polishing.

Comment: I wanted the keyword to be removed as well so your answer saved me a bit of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String foo(String str, String remove) {
     return str.substring(str.indexOf(remove));
}
```

Comment: If `str = "I need this words removed taken please"` and `remove = "I need this words removed "` then `str.indexOf(remove) = 0`. Which in return returns `str` from the very beginning, i.e. doesn't remove anything.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Which is correct behaviour since as OP shown in example part which was searched needs to stay (it is part before/after it which was removed).

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't write my previous comment because it doesn't give the desired result somehow. It's the naming that's bad. What do you expect as input to a `String` parameter named `remove?` The text to be removed or the text that should stay? And should it stay or should it be removed then?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Oh, in that case I misunderstood your comment (sorry for that) and you are right, name of that variable is not correct. But just in case your comment was cause of downvote I will leave my response for other people who (like me) may misunderstand it to not downvote it further (since IMO wrong variable name is not appropriate reason to down-vote).

Comment: @GeroldBroser well, in that case, this method is all wrong because it should check if input String is null.. but I just wrote it real quick. And it should also check if indexOf returns -1. The one who asked the question should put more effort to understand it and do all the fixing.

Comment: @Price Depends on the requirements. The OP didn't ask for checking for `null` or the existence of the string to be removed. In that case just the naming is bad. (And there is a difference between "bad" and "wrong".) But I'm out of here. I've seen this too many times: justifying own bad code with nil arguments and excuses.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I'm not justifying anything to you dude. I even called the method foo. so just think.

Answer (score 0):

Clean way to safely remove until a string

```
String input = "I need this words removed taken please";
String token = "taken";
String result = input.contains(token)
  ? token + StringUtils.substringAfter(string, token)
  : input;
```

> [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) functions are null-, empty-, and no match- safe

Answer (score 0):

Since OP provided clear requirements

> Remove the rest of the string **after** or **before** a certain word

and nobody has fulfilled those yet, here is my approach to the problem. There are certain rules to the implementation, but overall it should satisfy OP's needs, if he or she comes to revisit the question.

```
public static String remove(String input, String separator, boolean before) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(input);
  Objects.requireNonNull(separator);

  if (input.trim().equals(separator)) {
    return separator;
  }

  if (separator.isEmpty() || input.trim().isEmpty()) {
    return input;
  }

  String[] tokens = input.split(separator);

  String target;
  if (before) {
    target = tokens[0];
  } else {
    target = tokens[1];
  }

  return input.replace(target, "");
}
```